# Comparing data in two CSVs and creating a third CSV for matching data

Tags: python, pandas, csv

Let's say I have file1.csv:

```
OU                                   Mailfile   
CORP:Jenny Smith:                    mail/246802.nsf
"CORP:John Smith:,John Smith:"       mail/123456.nsf
STORE:Mary Poppins:                  mail/789012.nsf
STORE:Tony Stark:                    mail/345678.nsf
STORE:Carmen Sandiego:               mail/901234.nsf
NEWS:Peter Parker:                   mail/567890.nsf
NEWS:Clark Kent:                     mail/654321.nsf
STORES:store123                      mail/369121.nsf
```

Then file2.csv:

```
OU                      
CORP
STORE     
NEWS
```

For every line in file2.csv that has 'CORP', 'STORE', or 'NEWS', I want to search through file1.csv and create a file, such as STOREall.csv, CORPall.csv, and NEWSall.csv.

So a file like STOREall.csv should have:

```
OU                                   Mailfile
STORE:Mary Poppins:                  mail/789012.nsf
STORE:Tony Stark:                    mail/345678.nsf
STORE:Carmen Sandiego:               mail/901234.nsf
STORES:store123                      mail/369121.nsf
```

CORPall.csv:

```
OU                                   Mailfile
CORP:Jenny Smith:                    mail/246802.nsf
CORP:John Smith:,John Smith:         mail/123456.nsf
```

Then NEWSall.csv

```
OU                                   Mailfile
NEWS:Peter Parker:                   mail/567890.nsf
NEWS:Clark Kent:                     mail/654321.nsf
```

If I can also have it with just OU column and not Mailfile column, that would also be good. But I think I can just do a usecols=['OU'] for that.

---

I added more rows that I bumped into on the way:

```
OU                                   Mailfile   
CORP:Jenny Smith:                    mail/246802.nsf
"CORP:John Smith:,John Smith:"       mail/123456.nsf
STORE:Mary Poppins:                  mail/789012.nsf
STORE:Tony Stark:                    mail/345678.nsf
STORE:Carmen Sandiego:               mail/901234.nsf
NEWS:Peter Parker:                   mail/567890.nsf
NEWS:Clark Kent:                     mail/654321.nsf
STORES:store123                      mail/369121.nsf
NEWS:CORPmanager                     mail/137112.nsf
NEWS:STOREmanager                    mail/083561.nsf
```

I'm getting these outputs with the last two NEWS rows since there is corp in it too:

```
OU                                   Mailfile
CORP:Jenny Smith:                    mail/246802.nsf
CORP:John Smith:,John Smith:         mail/123456.nsf
NEWS:CORPmanager                     mail/137112.nsf
```

Comment: why doesn't STOREall have `STORE:Carmen Sandiego:`?

Comment: My mistake. It's there now. Was manually copying and pasting them and must've missed her.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could read both files into dataframes, loop through the values in the 'OU' column of file2.csv, filter the data from file1.csv and save as individual CSV files.

```py
import pandas as pd

data = pd.read_csv('file1.csv')

depts = pd.read_csv('file2.csv')

for dept in depts['OU']:
    df_dept = data[data['OU'].str.contains(dept)]
    df_dept['OU'].to_csv(f'{dept}all.csv', index=False)
```

Comment: This is a great answer. I did bump into one issue, and that's if there is a dept name in the actual name in the row, if department is NEWS but the word corpmanager is the name, like this  `NEWS:CORPmanager` , it'll put NEWS in CORP. I added more lines in my question above for reference.